# How do I remove duplicates in the "conc" column for each run without using any for loops, making my own function or using any packages?

Tags: r

I have this database from R called DNase (I've only attached a sample):

| Run | conc | density |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.04882812 | 0.017 |
| 1 | 0.04882812 | 0.018 |
| 1 | 0.19531250 | 0.121 |
| 1 | 0.19531250 | 0.124 |
| 1 | 0.39062500 | 0.206 |
| 1 | 0.39062500 | 0.215 |
| 1 | 0.78125000 | 0.377 |
| 1 | 0.78125000 | 0.374 |
| 1 | 1.56250000 | 0.614 |
| 1 | 1.56250000 | 0.609 |
| 1 | 3.12500000 | 1.019 |
| 1 | 3.12500000 | 1.001 |
| 1 | 6.25000000 | 1.334 |
| 1 | 6.25000000 | 1.364 |
| 1 | 12.50000000 | 1.730 |
| 1 | 12.50000000 | 1.710 |
| 2 | 0.04882812 | 0.045 |
| 2 | 0.04882812 | 0.050 |
| 2 | 0.19531250 | 0.137 |
| 2 | 0.19531250 | 0.123 |
| 2 | 0.39062500 | 0.225 |
| 2 | 0.39062500 | 0.207 |
| 2 | 0.78125000 | 0.401 |
| 2 | 0.78125000 | 0.383 |
| 2 | 1.56250000 | 0.672 |
| 2 | 1.56250000 | 0.681 |
| 2 | 3.12500000 | 1.116 |
| 2 | 3.12500000 | 1.078 |
| 2 | 6.25000000 | 1.554 |
| 2 | 6.25000000 | 1.526 |
| 2 | 12.50000000 | 1.932 |
| 2 | 12.50000000 | 1.914 |

I need to remove the duplicates in the conc column for run 1 and 2 without using loops.

I've tried this:

```
DNase[!duplicated(DNase$conc),]
```

but I get this:

| Run | conc | density |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.04882812 | 0.017 |
| 1 | 0.19531250 | 0.121 |
| 1 | 0.39062500 | 0.206 |
| 1 | 0.78125000 | 0.377 |
| 1 | 1.56250000 | 0.614 |
| 1 | 3.12500000 | 1.019 |
| 1 | 6.25000000 | 1.334 |
| 1 | 12.50000000 | 1.730 |

As you can see, I only get run 1 returned.

I need a way to segregate the runs and then remove duplicates from the conc column. I've tried using apply and also tried splitting the run as a list but nothing seems to work.

Really appreciate some guidance on this.
Thanks.

Comment: `duplicated` accepts also a data.frame and will look for duplicated rows. So just try: `DNase[!duplicated(DNase[,c("conc", "Run")]),]`

Answer (score 0):

Here another option using `dplyr` approach:

```
DNase %>% group_by(Run) %>% distinct(conc, .keep_all = TRUE)
```